# Publish WCF Service (or ASP.NET Web Application) using command line

Tags: .net, msbuild

I would like to simulate "Publish..." menu item from WCF Service project (or ASP.NET Web Application or...) context menu in Visual Studio 2008. I do not have a need to publish it to a running IIS instance, just to put the web content together with bin folder on some local dir. Is there any way to add it in post build events, or as a MSBuild task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer, thanks to this link: http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/
So, I have just modified the .csproj file of web application, and wrote this into AfterBuild target (that was already there):

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="##############Before build##################" Importance="high"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="publish"
        ContinueOnError="true"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="##############After build##################$(OutputFolder)" Importance="high"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectName).csproj"
           Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
           Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=publish\;OutDir=publish\bin\" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write an xcopy command to copy the files you need to the right location.
Microsoft has an article about [xcopy deployment for asp.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326355).

Once you have the command right you can put it into the Post Build actions so it automatically fires after a build.

Also see [VS Post Build Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371302/vs-post-build-event) for examples on copying just the dll output (note the use of $(TargetPath) &  $(TargetDir)).

Answer (score 0):

HI,
You should take a look at [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en). These are actually MSBuild files with Visual Studio GUI support. They will pre-compile your site. You can extend the behavior of these to copy the generated files to your web server.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: I'm having problems with Web Deployment Projects, since they deploy the .csproj file, obj folder and all the other unnecessary stuff. I would just like to reproduce the bahavior of "Publish..." command from the context menu of Web Application (not Web Site) project. Is there some easier way, or I have to exclude them manually, just like with the xcopy?