# How to register a DLL with RegAsm in Build EventS VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dll, registration, regasm

In every compile, output dll is changed in my program and after every compile, I must register dll again. I can register it via **Visual Studio Command Prompt** as **regasm** mydll.dll. But I dont want to do it everytime and I want it as automatically. After some research, I have detected that it is possible with Visual Studio from **Build Events** (project>properties). But I have never used Build Events before and I really cannot understand how it will be. Should I write my dll path to **pre-build event command line** ?

My dll location : *C:\Program Files (x86)\Onur\Client\Bin\client.dll*

My regasm location : *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe*

What should I write to pre-build and post-build commands in Build Events section ?

I tried them but even not compiled within it.
[VS Post Build Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371302/vs-post-build-event)

Comment: The more important detail you should take care of is *unregistering* the old version.  If you don't then you can make a pretty big mess of your registry.  Given the common need, this is all taken care of for you with a simple checkbox.  Project > Properties > Build tab > tick the "Register for COM interop".  Either way, these registry keys can only be modified by an elevated program so you *do* have to elevate VS.  Right-click the shortcut and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for reply. I checked that box and I realise that I must unregister-register the dll in every build of project. I will follow your answer and let you know result soon

Answer (score 4):

The RegAsm executable is located in the .Net Framework version folder but that is not by default in your path.

Fortunately there exist two Environment variables, namely `FrameworkDir` and `FrameWorkVersion` that you could use in your Post-build event. The MSDN documentation explains how to use [Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx).

For your specific case, the following does work in the Post-Build event (because your new dll need to be compiled and ready):

```batch
 $(frameworkdir)\$(frameworkversion)\regasm.exe "$(TargetPath)"
```

Notice how the `$(TargetPath)` is enclosed in double quotes to prevent any mishaps in case there is a space in your path.

If `frameworkdir` and/or `frameworkversion` don't exist you can use a fullpath but in that case you have to make sure that path exists on all machines you want to run that build. You might as well decide to bring the regasm.exe under source control and make it part of your buildtools.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "$(TargetPath)"
```

Keep in mind though that RegAsm requires elevated privileges so you would need to run Visual Studio already elevated to make the execution of RegAsm work in the first place.

Use the Build Output pane for diagnosing errors.

Comment: Hi Rene Thanks for reply. I have written to PostBuild section like that:
**$(frameworkdir)\$(frameworkversion)\regasm.exe  "$(C:\Program Files (x86)\Onur\Client\Bin\client.dll)"**

But It doesnt compile. But There is no error in Error List of visual studio. Output Result is -> https://snag.gy/vJ8uxK.jpg

Where do I miss ?

Thanks

Comment: I had to use the windows path to RegAsm

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "$(TargetPath)" /codebase /tlb`

Answer (score 0):

Developing COM Addins I find the code below useful (to be copied in the Post-Build text box). If target other versions of .NET Framework just need to add or modify the :REGISTRATION block as per your needs.

```
:REGISTRATION
IF "$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"=="v4.0" GOTO NET40
IF "$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"=="v3.5" GOTO NET20
IF "$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"=="v3.0" GOTO NET20
IF "$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"=="v2.0" GOTO NET20
GOTO END

:NET40
set FMWK="v4.0.30319"
GOTO REG

:NET20
set FMWK="v2.0.50727"
GOTO REG

:REG
IF "$(PlatformName)" == "AnyCPU" GOTO ANYCPU
IF "$(PlatformName)" == "x64" GOTO X64
GOTO END

:ANYCPU
IF EXIST "%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\%FMWK%\regasm.exe" 
"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\%FMWK%\regasm" /codebase "$(TargetPath)"
GOTO END

:X64
IF EXIST "%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\%FMWK%\regasm.exe" 
"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\%FMWK%\regasm" /codebase "$(TargetPath)"
GOTO END

:END
```