# Two different opencv_world builds

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll, path

I've got 2 builds of OpenCV 4.3 for MS Visual Studio. First one is the prebuilt version from GitHub and the second is the one I've built with CUDA support. They work without issues on their own. I've added the /bin/ folder of both builds to PATH. The problem is that **both** builds have the lib file named opencv_world430.lib and adding this file to 'Linker' -> 'Input' -> 'Additional Dependencies' causes the linker to find not the DLL I want but the DLL in the folder that is **upper** at the PATH list.

What I mean is that, when I create a project using **non-CUDA build** (properly adding include and lib directories to VC++ directories), the **DLL with CUDA is linked** because its filepath is at a higher position than the one I want.

The solution might be just swapping their places on PATH when I'm working with one but I want to ask if there is an easier way to handle this.

Also: I'm using VS2019 on Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe a search and replace in the project file its xml. Make sure you check it in to your version control before modifying.

Comment: For the dll path issue,  edit the order of the items in your windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried that but then I would have to edit the order of PATH variables and restart Visual Studio whenever I want to run the other version. Since one version has CUDA support, it heavily loads Nvidia Toolkit DLLs which causes a longer execution time. I suppose copying the necessary DLL to solution folder may be a solution but I want to know if I can tell the program where to look for DLLs in Visual Studio.

Comment: In the Visual Studio IDE you can set the PATH environmental variable on the debugging settings independently for each project you have.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could select `Properties->Build Event->Post-Build Event->Command Line` to copy dll to `Debug` folder. You could refer to the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371302/vs-post-build-event).

```
copy $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)..\..\someFolder\myoutput.dll
regasm $(TargetPath)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as _opencv_world.dll_ is linked way before `main()` is called, it is too late to call `LoadLibraryExA()` I believe (regarding [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ba82809-add0-43c7-930b-d1cdcadafd84/using-setdlldirectory?forum=vcgeneral) link). It seems I'm stuck with copying that dll into the execution folder.

Comment: I revised the answer,. I hope it will help you.