# How do I change where the dll dependencies are located for an application after building?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, executable

I am new to creating applications with Visual Studio and C++, and I am working on my first project. I couldn't find any answers on exactly what I was looking for, but maybe I didn't see something I should have - when a project solution has been built, and created into an exe, it has dependent DLLs in that same directory. Is there any specific way to change this to make the dependent DLLs appear in a subfolder inside that directory (ie. $(SolutionDir)Releases/Dependencies instead of $(SolutionDir)Releases)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `Output Directory` in project properties. For example:

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Dependencies
```

Comment: This moves both the application and DLLs into that folder. I'm attempting to only move the DLLs into that folder, while keeping the application where it is and allowing it to run correctly

Comment: @Chris :Just need to modify the project properties that generates the DLL(not exe project). In addition, if you are using release mode, you should have the DLL in the same directory as the **exe**.

Comment: Is your problem solved? [Post Build Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371302/vs-post-build-event) is also a way.